# Proper order of connection and ssl implementation, also "Bad Handshake"

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, pdo

Note: I resolved the problem I've been having for a while while typing this question, and I want to know if my resolution

I was having a "bad handshake" error come up from my sql database connection. It started when I tried to implement the ssl that I installed recently. I started off with the following code:

```
    $init =mysqli_init();

    $key="path/ftpd-rsa-key.pem";
    $cert="path/ftpd-rsa.pem";
    $ca="path/cert.pem";

    mysqli_ssl_set($init, $key, $cert, $ca, NULL, NULL);

//This line was my original connection script, which was working.
//$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database") or die(mysqli_connection_error());

    if(!$connection = mysqli_real_connect($init,"localhost", "username", "password", "database"))
      {
      die("Connect Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }
```

I tried various other things, including PDO, rebuilding Apache, and switching around the ssl certs and keys and stuff. Nothing was working. Eventually I tried just going back to the original code I was using and THEN implementing ssl:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database") or die(mysqli_connection_error());

$key="path/ftpd-rsa-key.pem";
$cert="path/ftpd-rsa.pem";
$ca="path/cert.pem";

mysqli_ssl_set($connection, $key, $cert, $ca, NULL, NULL);
```

And to my surprise, this worked. my page now appears to be totally functional, with no "bad handshake" error. However, due to the fact that I didn't find any tutorials or materials building it this way, I was wondering if this is actually secure. The entire point of ssl is for security, and doing it this way the connection starts without ssl. Is that a problem?

Additionally, any information about the "bad handshake" error and what causes it would be useful. If we could create/link a guide or a full explanation of it and what causes it, that would be useful for future programmers, as the suggested solutions I found while googling it range from junking your server and moving on to switching to PDO to downgrading MySQL.

Comment: SSL only protects the communication between PHP and MySQL from interception by eavesdroppers.  When connecting to a MySQL server on `localhost`, it is utterly pointless (and likely to be ignored if the server is reachable over a socket/named-pipe).

Comment: This is on my server. My password is also not password, and the path to the files is also not `path/`, to be clear.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second snippet tells me that your server is not configured/running with certificates. This is the source of the bad handshake.

When you initiate a SSL connection to MySQL (using your first snippet), both client and server need to be fully configured to do so. On MySQL, this includes SSL certs, CA cert, etc. This is done via CLI. This is typically done using the `--ssl-ca`, `--ssl-cert` and `--ssl-key` `mysqld`command-line arguments.

Your first snippet is failing because MySQL is not returning a valid SSL handshake as a result of this.

Your second snippet is working because your mysqli SSL set is happening after the connection already happens - i.e. it has no effect. The connection effectively dropped down to non-SSL already.

Consider generating a certificate for `mysqld`, restarting it with the proper parameters, and seeing if this works.